# Q: How to trigger a Batch file from a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file

**Explanation:**

I have a finished coded Batch-file. This Batch file is called X.bat and has 3 questions, which comes linear:

1. “Press any key to continue” < It should automatically press anything to proceed
2. “Do you like what you see? < The answer should automatic be “yes” or “Y”
3. How would you rate this from 1-10?” < The answer should just be choice number “5”.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
echo off
x.bat
```

**Mission:**

I want to trigger the main batch-file with "Enter" -> "Y" -> "5" as events, so the .bat initiator, wont get the questions above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start one batch file from another, you can use the call command:

https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: I could not get it to work. I manage to remove the first "Enter" thing by removing a "Pause" in the main .BAT. But I cannot figure out how to send a "Y" followed by "5" from one Batch to another Batch-file.